# Is there a way to override the file/line information reported by console.log?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a transpiler that generates JavaScript code from a custom language. The `print` statements from the original language get translated into `console.log`. However, when the output of console log shows up in the developer console, it obviously displays the JavaScript file name and line number but that isn't very useful to my users.

Is there a way to override the file name and line number for `console.log` so that I can have my code generator pass in the original file and line information?

Turning this: [image]

...into this: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Trying to figure this out myself has led me here, so I'll share what I found after an afternoon of research: **apparently not**. The best you can do is to add the original file&line information to be included within your log message, resulting in logs like these:

```
2/6/2021, 22:27:06 [info ] [background-main.js:31] loaded user settings from localStorage:
{
 "settings": {
  "downloadAttachments": true,
  "useLostAndFound": true,
  "debug": true,
  "downloadInterval": "3000"
 }
}
2/6/2021, 22:27:06 [info ] [download.js:95] started download interval (intervalID "2") with "3000" ms interval
2/6/2021, 22:27:06 [info ] [background-main.js:51] wrote settings to localStorage:
{
 "downloadAttachments": true,
 "useLostAndFound": true,
 "debug": true,
 "downloadInterval": "3000"
}
```

- [My implementation to allow *console.log/.info/.warn/.error* to write to a log cache AND to console from one common call.](https://github.com/dogpixels/patreon-helper/blob/master/js/logging.js)
- [Someone else's implementation I found that uses a simliar approach.](https://gist.github.com/brettz9/01b8de732206db0926166e11211e5641#file-console-log-js)